# Hashmap not returning all values

Tags: java

I'm learning how to use hashmaps and I'm having some issues here. I created two classes called Zoo and Animals, and I joined both classes using an Hashmap:

```
private HashMap<Zoo, Animals> zoo;
```

I built a method to add data into the hashmap:

```
public void setAnimal(Zoo zoo, Animals animal ){
    zoo.put(zoo, animal);
}
```

And I'm inserted the follwing values into the hashmap:

```
   Main main = new Main();

   Zoo zoo1 = new Zoo("France", 1);
   Zoo zoo2 = new Zoo("Spain", 2);

   Animals gorilla = new Animals(2015, "Gorilla");
   Animals frog = new Animals(2018, "Frog");

   Animals zebra = new Sedan(2016, "zebra");
   Animals lion= new Sedan(2016, "lion");

   main.setAnimal(zoo1, gorilla);
   main.setAnimal(zoo2, frog);

   main.setAnimal(zoo2, lion);
   main.setAnimal(zoo2, zebra);
```

And I built a method to print the Zoos and the respective animals in there:

```
 String text = "";

        for(Map.Entry<Zoo, Animals> entry : zoo.entrySet()) {

            Zoo key = entry.getKey();
            Animals value = entry.getValue();

            text += key.toString() + "\n";

            text += value.toString() + "\n";


        }

        return text;
```

But I just get this:

```
France 1 
gorilla

Spain 2 
Zebra
```

Instead of

```
France 1
Gorilla

Spain 2
frog
lion
zebra
```

How can I get the full animals list?

Comment: Basically, the second parameter, `Animals` needs to be a list of animals rather than just one animal: `<Zoo,List<Animal>>`.

Comment: `Map` maps a key to a *single* value. If you keep on calling `put` for the same key, you overwrite the previous value.

Comment: A map that returns multiple values is sometimes called a Multi-Map.  Apache commons has one, though the standard Java API does not: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html